# MySQL CONCAT table filtering syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, syntax-error, concatenation

I'm getting an error "**Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY p.`promo_code` ASC' at line 1**" on my order by clauses and im not sure why, when I un-CONCAT the query it seems to work fine.

Am I missing something?  Here's my code:

```
    SET _select = CONCAT( "SELECT p.`promo_code` AS code, p.`name` AS username, p.`company` AS company " );
    SET _select = CONCAT( _select, " FROM `promos` AS p" );

    SET _where = CONCAT( " WHERE 1 = 1");

    IF _promoCode IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " AND ( p.`promo_code` LIKE '%", _promoCode, "%'" );
    END IF;
    IF _companyName IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " AND ( p.`company` LIKE '%", _companyName, "%'" );
    END IF;
    IF _userName IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " AND ( p.`name` LIKE '%", _userName, "%'" );
    END IF;

    -- SET _where_total = _where;

    #SORT option protocols, 1 is promocode, 2 is company, 3 is name; Second number is ASC/DESC
    IF _sortOrder IS NOT NULL THEN
        CASE _sortOrder
            WHEN 10 THEN
                SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " ORDER BY p.`promo_code` ASC" );
            WHEN 11 THEN
                SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " ORDER BY p.`promo_code` DESC" );
            WHEN 20 THEN
                SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " ORDER BY p.`company` ASC" );
            WHEN 21 THEN
                SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " ORDER BY p.`company` DESC" );
            WHEN 30 THEN
                SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " ORDER BY p.`name` ASC" );
            WHEN 31 THEN
                SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " ORDER BY p.`name` DESC" );
            ELSE
                SELECT "Please use valid sort protocol";
        END CASE;
    END IF;

    /*SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " LIMIT ", _start, ", ", _records );*/

    SET @query = CONCAT( _select, _where );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET _select_total = "SELECT COUNT( p.`promo_code` ) AS total_matching_promos ";
    SET _select_total = CONCAT( _select_total, " FROM `promos` AS p " );

    SET @query = CONCAT( _select_total, _where_total );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

There are some opening parenthesis in the conditional WHERE clauses:

```
IF _promoCode IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " AND **(** p.`promo_code` LIKE '%", _promoCode, "%'" );
END IF;
IF _companyName IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " AND **(** p.`company` LIKE '%", _companyName, "%'" );
END IF;
IF _userName IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET _where = CONCAT( _where, " AND **(** p.`name` LIKE '%", _userName, "%'" );
END IF;
```

Deleted those and moved `SET _where_total = _where;`
to just before `SET @query = CONCAT( _select, _where );`

Don't blindly copy paste code folks :P